# Css selectors dropdown lang chooser python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VaDN.jpg)

How to use `css selectors` for `dropdown` language `selection English`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#lang-chooser').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes :**

1. You can not use `Select` class from `Selenium`. Because if you see the `outer HTML`, it's built using `div` and `span tags.` `Select` class is only meant for `drop down` built using `Select` and `option` tag.
2. We can directly `click` on `drop down` first then `we can select the option` the we want using `.click()`
3. Use `Explicit waits` for `dynamic waiting.`
4. I am using `div[data-value='en-GB'][role='option'` `CSS_SELECTOR` to select `English (United Kingdom)`. In case of any other option you'd wish to select, you'd have to change the css selector, basically this part `[data-value='en-GB']`

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#lang-chooser"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-value='en-GB'][role='option']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp") the url login page fix the problem and also ccs fine but the url do the job thanks